# N-ary tree in Go

Tags: go

I am evaluating Go to replace Node.js infrastructure and I am not sure how to create a structure to represent a N-ary tree.

In JavaScript, I parse a file to build up a hierarchy of geographic locations of arbitrary depth. Here is an example:

```
{
  'country1': {
    'area1': {
      'town1': {}, 
      'town2': {}
    },
    'area2': {
      'town3': {}
    }
  }
}
```

Towns could expand into specific roads and so on. The hierarchy doesn't have a fixed depth.

How can I create an equivalent structure in Go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to have arbitrary depth, then it might be worth it to create a default struct that can be nested:

```
type area struct {
    Name string
    //Any other area info
    Sections []*area
}
```

Slices of pointers aren't initialized when creating a new struct object, so it's a valid construct.  Declare `a.Sections = new([]*area)` and append `area` pointers to it.  You will have `len(a.Sections)` or a `for range` loop for use in the tree traversal.

Parsing and traversal would be coded recursively, so you would need a type identifier if you treat different areas in different ways.

Comment: How do you marshal it to JSON? I tried this but doesn't work! https://play.golang.org/p/ActW53nDLP

Comment: JSON won't marshal unexported fields.  Be sure to capitalize everything you want in the JSON output:  https://play.golang.org/p/s_Z56r620F

Answer (score 2):

Let's review the hierarchy.

- At the top level, you map country names to country objects.
- Each country object maps area names to area objects.
- Each area object maps town names to town objects.

In Go, you can implement each level of the hierarchy as a `map[string]*Something`, with the last level consisting of `Town` objects that contain various information about towns:

```
type Country map[string]*Area

type Area map[string]*Town

type Town struct {
    Name                string
    Population          int
    Latitude, Longitude float64
}
```

The sample hierarchy that you've given in your question would then look like this:

```
countries := map[string]*Country{
    "country1": &Country{
        "area1": &Area{
            "town1": &Town{},
            "town2": &Town{},
        },
        "area2": &Area{
            "town3": &Town{},
        },
    },
}
```

If you don't want to map to concrete types, you can use `map[string]interface{}`, but then you'll need type assertions to work with the values. Here is a code sample taken from Zack Bloom's article on [Go and JSON](https://eager.io/blog/go-and-json/):

```
var parsed map[string]interface{}
data := []byte(`
    {
        "id": "k34rAT4",
        "age": 24
    }
`)
err := json.Unmarshal(data, &parsed)
idString := parsed["id"].(string)
```

Comment: I edited my question as I forgot to mention that it's of arbitrary depth; for example, towns could be broken down into something arbitrary like zip/post code, road, etc; so it is not fixed.

Comment: I think I'm nearly got my solution using `map[string]interface{}`; just discovered `interface{}`

Comment: @jimjampez if you're new to Go, make sure you fully understand what you're doing when you use `interface{}`. Avoid it if possible.

Comment: It is Go's equivalent to `void*` in C?

Comment: Kind of. [This document](http://jordanorelli.com/post/32665860244/how-to-use-interfaces-in-go) discusses it. But if you know the types and structure of what you're going to have you should let the type system work for you and not check things at runtime with type assertions. I missed that you said that it's of arbitrary depth but it's something to be aware of.